# Perl subroutine not working in loop

Tags: perl, loops, subroutine

I tried writing a simple code to find whether a number can be expressed as the sum of primes or not, in Perl. The sample code is as shown:

```
sub funcIsPrime {
    my $num = $_[0];    
    my $isPrime = 1;
    for($i= 2; $i <= $num/2; $i++){
        if($num%$i == 0){
            $isPrime = 0;
            last;
        }
    }
    return $isPrime;
}

#my $num = <>;
my $num = 20;
for($i = 2; $i <= $num/2; $i++){
    print "$i\t";
    my $j = $num-$i;
    print "$j\n";

    if(funcIsPrime($i) and funcIsPrime($j)){    # Line x
        print "$num = $i + $j\n";
    }
}
```

The function call statements in Line x do not execute. The same line when put outside the loop works fine. What can be the possible solution? Please help. Thank you.

Comment: Re "*The function call statements in Line x do not execute.*", This is easily disproved by adding `warn("!");` inside of `funcIsPrime`. What problem are you actually having?

Comment: Always use `use strict; use warnings qw( all );`!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue is missing `my` in variable declarations. Perl won't let you run the program if you include `use warnings;` and `use strict;`:

```
Global symbol "$i" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my $i"?) at test.pl line 22.
Execution of test.pl aborted due to compilation errors.
```

Here's simplified working code (you can search for factors up to the square root of n, by the way, although this isn't a perfect or efficient prime test by any means):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

sub isPrime {
    my $num = $_[0];    

    for (my $i = int sqrt $num; $i > 1; $i--) {
        if ($num % $i == 0) {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    return 1;
}

my $num = 20;

for (my $i = 2; $i <= $num / 2; $i++) {
    my $j = $num - $i;

    if (isPrime($i) && isPrime($j)) {
        print "$num = $i + $j\n";
    }
}
```

#### Output

```
20 = 3 + 17
20 = 7 + 13
```

Comment: Did you mean: `my $i = int sqrt($num)`?

Comment: `int sqrt $num` can give you a number less than the one you expect because of floating point error, so `my $i = 1 + int sqrt $num` would be safer.

Comment: Thank a lot. It worked. I got where I had gone wrong.

Comment: @ikegami I considered that--I used my sub to solve [PE #7](https://projecteuler.net/problem=7) as a basic test and it was accurate. Do you have an example of an input it fails on? If so, I'll change it. I can see I probably should have left it same as OP instead of attempting to head down the optimization wormhole :)

Comment: @ggorlen, My math library appears to be very smart and returns the exact integer --not a billionths above or below-- for sqrt(n^2) for integers n=1..100. There's no saying that other math libraries are that smart. though